# PhpStorm - how to show run npm scripts

Tags: node.js, phpstorm, angular

I am following an example for Angular 2 steps:

1. Open PhpStorm > Edit > Settings > Plugins > Search > nodejs > Install
2. I follow the instructions in [this video](https://egghead.io/lessons/angular-2-webstorm-setting-up-angular-2) at 27 seconds into the video
3. I right click `package.json` and choose "run npm"
4. Indexing has finished. I right click `package.json` and there is no option to - show npm scripts.

How can I get the "show npm scripts" to show?

Comment: Works fine here. What do you see then? Do you see that command in context menu **before** executing "Run 'npm install'" command?

Comment: no i didn't. I do have an option to click Run 'node update'. I click that and it runs, showing some logs of dependencies unmet. Otherwise it runs through ok, and the option to click "show npm scripts" still doesn't exist after that.

Comment: Well .. what's your IDE version then? Make sure it's latest stable 10.0.3 or EAP v11 build.